# How to use dynamic insert and check on a loop under cursors in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, plsql

```
create or replace package IR is
procedure chkval;
end IR;

create or replace package body IR is
procedure chkval is
lheat IR_SENSE.heat%type;
cursor cur is select heat from IR_SENSE;
begin
open cur;
loop
insert into IR_SENSE values(to_number(substr(dbms_random.random,1,4)));
fetch cur into lheat;
dbms_output.put_line(lheat);
commit;
exit when lheat>4000;
exit when cur%notfound;
end loop;
close cur;
end;
end IR`enter code here`
```

Here, I am trying to perform dynamic insert in a table(values are from a IR sensor as temp) and I need to raise the alarm (exit my program) if the value crosses a threshold.

Comment: What part needs to be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; I didn't write a package (nor a stored procedure) - this is an anonymous PL/SQL block which you'll easily rewrite to anything you want.

Creating test case:

```
SQL> create table ir_sense (heat number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into ir_sense (heat)
  2  select round(dbms_random.value * 7500)
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 1000;

1000 rows created.

SQL>
```

Code & its output:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_treshold number := 8000;
  3    l_cnt      number := 0; -- number of values lower than L_TRESHOLD
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select heat from ir_sense
  6                  order by heat  -- so that I wouldn't exit too fast
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
 10      if cur_r.heat > 4000 then
 11         dbms_output.put_line('Treshold reached after ' || l_cnt || ' readings');
 12         exit;
 13      end if;
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /
Treshold reached after 525 readings

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: a new approach]**

P_SENSE procedure inserts values if they are lower than 4000 and returns 'N' as "PAR_STOP" parameter (i.e. "don't stop loading"); otherwise, it returns "Y".

```
SQL> create table ir_sense (heat number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_sense (par_heat in number, par_stop out varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    if par_heat > 4000 then
  4       -- stop loading
  5       par_stop := 'Y';
  6    else
  7       insert into ir_sense(heat) values (par_heat);
  8       par_stop := 'N';
  9    end if;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: WHILE loop simulates values you're receiving from the device, and keeps doing that until the P_SENSE procedure returns PAR_STOP = Y (i.e. stop loading).

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_heat number;
  3    l_stop varchar2(1) := 'N';
  4  begin
  5    -- simulating temperature readings
  6    while l_stop = 'N' loop
  7      l_heat := round(dbms_random.value * 7500);
  8      p_sense(l_heat, l_stop);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from ir_sense;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         3

SQL> select * from ir_sense;

      HEAT
----------
       187
      2328
      1072
```

Comment: The main part of my question is to perform the check under if condition when the enteries are dynamic. Here you have already created one table with limited enteries, and I have tried this block already :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying. Your code: `cursor cur is select heat from IR_SENSE;` is exactly what I'm doing - selecting values from a table, only that I'm doing it in a cursor FOR loop. I don't know what you meant to do by `insert into IR_SENSE` (the same table you're selecting from) again. Could you explain where those values (temperature readings) come from? Your code should insert them into a table, so - a procedure with a parameter might do the job. Have a look at my edited answer.